# How to save the image from DecorationImage with its colorFilter - Flutter

Tags: image, dart, flutter, colorfilter

I have a `DecorationImage` and I apply some color filters to it.

I simply cannot find any way to get the image with its `colorFilter` together.

```
Container(
    height: 150,
    width:  50,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      image: new DecorationImage(
        colorFilter: _colorFilter,
        image: FileImage(_image),
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

I want to be able to get this `_image` file with its existing `colorFilter`. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to save in external storage of the device?

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Sorry, maybe I phrased it wrong, the problem is not the "saving" part, I need to extract this somehow, it's okay if I can just extract it to a File object.

Comment: I am afraid you can't extract it this way. AFAIK, the `colorFilter` is just used to be displayed on the screen, you can't extract something like this

Comment: I see, that's quite unfortunate, thanks a lot though!

Comment: @CopsOnRoad Is there any other way I can achieve this apart from DecorationImage maybe?

Comment: Let's wait for someone to provide a better solution, I don't claim myself to be an expert on this.

Comment: you could use [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/screenshot). Wrap this container inside this widget and you can take a screenshot of that widget.